# Filter the results with the map method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter the array with the number inside the mode and get values less than or equal to the number inside the mode.
Then display the results using the map method inside `<li>`
But unfortunately musk is not working here and I do not know where I have a problem

```js
class AvailableProducts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const Products = [
      { id: "1", name: "Item1", price: 10000 },
      { id: "2", name: "Item2", price: 20000 },
      { id: "3", name: "Item3", price: 32000 },
      { id: "4", name: "Item4", price: 45000 },
      { id: "5", name: "Item5", price: 12000 },
      { id: "6", name: "Item6", price: 52000 },
      { id: "7", name: "Item7", price: 67000 },
      { id: "8", name: "Item8", price: 40000 },
    ];
    const budge = this.props.budge;
    const result = Products.filter(price => (price <= budge));
    const showResuli = result.map((Product) => (
      <li key={Product.id}>{Product}</li>
    ));

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Result</legend>
        <ul>{showResuli}</ul>
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { budget: "35000" };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Enter Price</label>
        </div>
        <AvailableProducts budge={this.state.budget} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think you mean `Products.filter(({price}) => price <= budge)`

Comment: @George I corrected the code the way you did, but the result is still not displayed

Comment: You also need to make sure you're passing budget as a prop to AvailableProducts.

Comment: @2Steaks Is it possible to edit my code correctly? Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams to be the line where you filter your array.

`const result = Products.filter(price <= budge);`

You need to provide a function to the filter function.

Like this :

`const result = Products.filter(({price}) => (price <= budge));`

And you can't render an "object" like you did here :

```js
result.map(Product => (
  <li key={Product.id}>{Product}</li> // but `Product.name` or thing like this
))
```

Here is a functionnal exemple:

```js
class AvailableProducts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const Products = [
      { id: "1", name: "Item1", price: 10000 },
      { id: "2", name: "Item2", price: 20000 },
      { id: "3", name: "Item3", price: 32000 },
      { id: "4", name: "Item4", price: 45000 },
      { id: "5", name: "Item5", price: 12000 },
      { id: "6", name: "Item6", price: 52000 },
      { id: "7", name: "Item7", price: 67000 },
      { id: "8", name: "Item8", price: 40000 },
    ];
    const budge = this.props.budge;
    const result = Products.filter(({price}) => (price <= budge));

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Result</legend>
        <ul>
          {result.map(Product => (
            <li key={Product.id}>{Product.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I corrected the code the way you did, but the result is still not displayed

Comment: So please add a functionnal codesandbox with not any import error and I will help you.

Comment: And this kind of error above it can be easy find by your IDE and not by human is Stackoverflow...

Comment: I modified my code and it works now but the results are not displayed

Comment: Unfortunately I do not find any error in the code but the results are not displayed

Comment: I find error, you need to learn how to debug a project. Please console.log everything and you will find. I do that and i edit my answer to the right answer.

Comment: You can't display an object as a string. And please use functionnal component if you can, class component is old, and please take more time to read and check the documentation, this kind of error is not realy hard, you just need to `console.log`