# React how to filter the result using the user input?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to filter the data based on the input in `rarity-input`. I've found that I should use [.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472967/filter-the-results-with-the-map-method-in-react) on my map function but I can't figure out how to do it.
Basically in the `rarity-inpupt` the user insert a value which is `d.id`, it can only returns 1 object

```
<div id='row'>
     <input className="rarity-input"/>
     <div className="rarity-item">
         {props.data
             ? props.data.map((d, i) => (
                   <div className='cards'>
                      <div className="card">
                          <img src={d.image}/>
                               <div className="card-body">
                                   <h2>Santa #{d.id}</h2>
                                   <h3>Rarity score: {d.rarity}</h3>
                               </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                  ))
                  : 'Loading...'}
       </div>
 </div>
```

[EDIT]

I'm trying something like this

```
export const Rarity = (props) => {

    this.state = {
        idTarget : ''
    }

    function updateInput(event) {
        this.setState({idTarget : event.target.value})

    }

    return (
        <div id='rarity' className='text-center'>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 section-title'>
                    <h2>Rarity</h2>
                    <p>
                        This tool allows you to check the rarity of your Santa by inserting his serial number !
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        (for example you want the rarity of #14, simply insert : 14)
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id='row'>
                    <label>
                        <input className="rarity-input" onChange={this.updateInput}/>
                    </label>
                    <div className="rarity-item">
                        {props.data
                            ? props.data.filter(...).map((d, i) => (
                                <div className='cards'>
                                    <div className="card">
                                        <img src={d.image}/>
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                            <h2>Santa #{d.id}</h2>
                                            <h3>Rarity score: {d.rarity}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))
                            : 'Loading...'}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: How are you getting the user input `value` ?, please share complete code.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck, the user insert value in `<input className="rarity-input"/>` but I don't know how to use it to filter `d.id == rarity-input.value`

Comment: Please post the complete code in your question so someone can provide you with a solution.

Comment: I did and I added the news changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you have to save the user input in a state, after that you have to filter your data based on this state (remember the case that the input is empty it should render the full list.

Note: As you are new to react, I tried to keep it simple but it's an ugly solution, to enhance it you should use useMemo to save the filtered data, destructure your props and try to keep your code declarative.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ComponentName = (props) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div id="row">
      <input className="rarity-input" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      <div className="rarity-item">
        {props.data
          ? props.data
              .filter((item) => (inputValue?.length ? item.id === inputValue : true))
              .map((d, i) => (
                <div className="cards" key={d.id}>
                  <div className="card">
                    <img src={d.image} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <h2>Santa #{d.id}</h2>
                      <h3>Rarity score: {d.rarity}</h3>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
          : 'Loading...'}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to store user input in state like below.

```
const [data ,setData] = useState("");
<input className = "rarity-input" value = {data} onChange = {()=> setData(e.target.value}  />
```

Then use this state to filter data. You can filter data based on id like below.

```
props.data.filter(item => item.id === data)
```

Save this result in any variable & map resulted in data in the return statement.

Comment: Also right ! Thank you :D